# Create button with rounded corners and gradient background programmatically

Tags: android, android-button, android-drawable

I have to draw buttons depending on the user.
These buttons have to be rounded corners and with gradient background.

To achieve this result, here is my code that create a button:

```
        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        GradientDrawable gradientNormal = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,
                new int[] { cc.getColorSelector()[1], cc.getColorSelector()[0] });
        GradientDrawable gradientPressed = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,
                new int[] { cc.getColorSelector()[0], cc.getColorSelector()[1] });
        StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, gradientPressed);
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {}, gradientNormal);
        RoundRectShape rect = new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 30, 30, 30,
                30, 30, 30, 30, 30 }, null, null);
        ShapeDrawable bg = new ShapeDrawable(rect);
```

The cc.getColorSelector() returns just the integer color.

Now I need to merge the shape of ShapeDrawable with the color of StateListDrawable, in order to have a single drawable I can use as background of my button.

How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    final Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, arBtn.getWidth(), 0,
                    new int[]{
                            Color.parseColor("#4B94FF"),
                            Color.parseColor("#578FFA"),
                            Color.parseColor("#7881EE"),
                            Color.parseColor("#AE6ADA"),
                            Color.parseColor("#EF4FC2")}, //substitute the correct colors for these
                    new float[]{
                            0, 0.125f, 0.375f, 0.687f, 1},
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            return lg;
        }
    };
    PaintDrawable p = new PaintDrawable();
    p.setShape(new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 30, 30, 30,
            30, 30, 30, 30, 30 }, null, null));
    p.setShaderFactory(sf);
    btn.setBackground((Drawable) p);
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation? A big code block alone isn't always self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

> ONLY GRADIENT AS BACKGROUND

You can achieve this result with `GradientDrawable` like so:

```
button.background = getRoundedTintedDrawable(Color.BLUE) // change it to any color
.
.
.

private fun getRoundedTintedDrawable(color: Int): Drawable {
    GradientDrawable().run {
        // set rounded corners
        cornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS // in dp

        // set the gradient type
        gradientType = GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT // there is radial, oval, etc..

        // set gradient orientation
        orientation = GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT // right to left, top to bottom, etc...

        // gradient colors 
        colors = intArrayOf(Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE) // change to any array of colors

        return this
    }
}
```

> CLICK EVENT EFFECTS USING getRoundedTintedDrawable

If you want to have any click events effects, you need to use the  `StateListDrawable` with the View state and the `getRoundedTintedDrawable` method from above:

```
button.background = setColorSelection(Color.BLUE) // change it to any color
.
.
.
private fun setColorSelection(color: Int): StateListDrawable {
    StateListDrawable().run {
        setExitFadeDuration(PRESS_DURATION)
        addState(ViewState.DISABLED.state, getRoundedTintedDrawable(getColorWithAlpha(color)))
        addState(ViewState.PRESSED.state, getRoundedTintedDrawable(getDarkerColor(color)))
        addState(ViewState.DEFAULT.state, getRoundedTintedDrawable(color))
        return this
    }
}
```

Here is the View state abstraction enum:

```
/**
* Possible view states list
* **/
internal enum class ViewState (val state: IntArray) {
   PRESSED (intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed)),
   FOCUSED (intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_focused)),
   DISABLED (intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_enabled)),
   CHECKED (intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked)),
   DEFAULT (intArrayOf())
}
```

And here is and color calculator to get a darker and a more translucent color:

```
  /**
 * @return a [Color] darker than [color]
 * **/
private fun getDarkerColor(color: Int): Int{
    val hsv = FloatArray(3)
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv)
    hsv[2] *= BRIGHTNESS_REDUCTION // change the brightness of the color
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv)
}

// @return a [Color] more translucent than [color]
private fun getColorWithAlpha(color: Int, ratio: Float = ALPHA_FADE_DISABLE): Int {
    return Color.argb((Color.alpha(color) * ratio).roundToInt(), Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color))
}
```

We can set some default values to help us to change how the effects interact with the button.

```
private companion object {
    const val BRIGHTNESS_REDUCTION = 0.8f
    const val PRESS_DURATION = 200 //ms
    const val ALPHA_FADE_DISABLE = 0.4f
    const val DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.GRAY
    const val DEFAULT_RADIUS = 10f // dp
}
```

Hope that helps :)